# How To Attach A Card To An Image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOIQc.jpg)So I am trying to get the last image to fall into the bottom left of the middle image however I can't get my image latch on to the bottom, instead, even if I make a new row, or use clearfix, the image will attach on to images/text/breaks below it.

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x90" class="img-fluid" width="100%">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x400" class="img-fluid" width="100%">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x400" class="img-fluid card-img-overlay mt-auto" width="30%" height="30%">
```

Also I am trying to get my code all in html and none in css so bootstrap answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `col` class of bootstrap for that.

```html
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x90" class="img-fluid" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x400" class="img-fluid" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/970x400" class="img-fluid card-img-overlay mt-auto" width="30%"
        height="30%">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought I tried this but, it works now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can explain a little more, maybe with screenshoots...  I am guessing you are trying to work with CSS and Bootstrap... right?   Please create a link for your code or send the code ...  It´s easier this way... Give us more information so we can help you better!  Take care buddy!

Comment: I added the image